# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This isn't a hierarchical URI

Tags: android, youtube

I want to play the youtube video url using following code.
But I can see this error.

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.youtube.tv/com.google.android.apps.youtube.tv.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This isn't a hierarchical URI.

this is my code.

```
  Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:GGjVd7mLM3k"));
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            startActivity(appIntent);
```

Comment: can you share whole code its working properly for me.Add manifest file and MainActivity code with XML